# Can you access a Django Model "property" from it's ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms

I have a Django model class with a non-model-field property, ex:

```
def _get(self):
    return "something"
description = property(_get)
```

I'm using the model class with in a ModelForm / ModelFormset.  Is there any way to access the property from the form / formset?  If not, what's best practice for including extra "display" data in a django formset?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your ModelForm was initialized with an instance of a Model, then you can access it through the `instance` attribute.  From the [ModelForm docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method):

> Also, a model form instance bound to a model object will contain a self.instance attribute that gives model form methods access to that specific model instance.